# How to show option for my live wallpaper, Home AND Lock screen both on preview screen programmatically

Tags: android

I have a live wallpaper service when i show the preview of the live wallpaper through below code i can see only single button "Set as wallpaper" I want to show the option to set on both lock and both screens and show message like in below screenshot in samsung galaxy s6 and s7 devices.

What change i can do in my code. Please suggest.
Thanks

My code is:-

```
intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
                intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                        new ComponentName(mContext, LiveWallpaperService.class));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SET_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
```

[Click here to show screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmgk1.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can help with what you trying to accomplish: 

on Samsung devices adding extra data to Intent helps set wallpaper on Lockscreen as well:

```
intent.putExtra("SET_LOCKSCREEN_WALLPAPER", true);
```

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Please limit the answer fields to answers only. Do not ask questions as part of your answer. If you have a question, then [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).